# Look for multiple occurances of a character using regex

Tags: python, regex

i using the pattern `pat='dd|dddd'` , and i thought it would either match dd or dddd.

```
import re
re.search(pat,'ddd')
re.search(pat,'ddddd')
```

any number of d(s) matches for that matter why is it so ?

Comment: In addition to the answers already given, consider using `re.match` instead of `re.search` to avoid finding matches beyond the start of the string. (You still need to anchor the end to get your desired behavior, so still pay attention to those other answers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to anchor the regular expression somehow.  A regular expression searches within strings to find a pattern.  So "dd" will be found in "dddddddd" at offset 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.

If you want to match only entire strings try `^dd$`.  ^ matches the beginning of a string, $ matches the end.  So  `^(dd|dddd)$` will have the behavior you want.

If you want it to match only dd or dddd but within a string.  Then you might want to use: `[^d](dd|dddd)[^d]`  Which will match "anything that isn't d" then either two or four ds then "anything that isn't d"

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by Charles Duffy, `search` isn't really the function that you should be using. Try using `match` or even `findall`.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('dd|dddd','dd').group()
'dd'
>>> re.findall('dd|dddd','dd')
['dd']
>>> re.match('dd|dddd','ddddd').group()
'dd'
>>> re.match('dddd|dd','ddddd').group()
'dddd'
```